# How to parse an object from select to integer in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

When using angular ngOptions in select, my model attribute is updated with object, not its id, what's desired in my case. I've tried `$parsers` and `$formatters`, but it doesn't work.

Basically I want instead of sending `{id:0,name:"exercise"}`
from

```
$scope.room_types = [
  {id:0,name:"exercise"},
  {id:1,name:"laboratory"},
  {id:2,name:"lecture"}
];
```

to send its id value (and ofc the other way round). Is there any nice way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are looking for something like this:

```
<select ng-model="selectedRoomId" ng-options="room_type.id as room_type.name for room_type in room_types"></select>
```

This will display:

```
exercise 
laboratory 
lecture
```

and bind the `id` to `selectedRoomId`.

Here is a [simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JZ7J9/1/).

Comment: And it doesn't solve the problem. I want model.room_type to be integer with id, not room_type object. It may happen only when sending (that replacement).

Comment: `selectedRoomId` will hold the ID of the selected room. Isn`t that what you want to achieve?

Comment: Of course it works, sorry :) and thank you very much